# Unique open balls

Tags: real-analysis

In an arbitrary metric space (X,d), not $\mathbb{R^n}$, does it have to be the case that two open balls $B_r(x)=B_s(y)$ have a unique centre and radius?

My guess is no, but I can't come up with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use the discrete metric.

Comment: That's what I thought originally but using the discrete metric r=s=1 and $x\neq y$, the balls only has a singleton element in it. i.e. $B_r(x)={x}$  and $B_s(y)={y}$.

Comment: For any $x,y\in X$, $B_2(x)=B_3(y)=X$.

Comment: Is the universe $X$ open? I thought it was neither open or closed?

Comment: Yes $X$ is always open, by definition of a topology.